# Using SPIdev with Python and Raspberry PI

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, sensors, spi

I'm trying to read light angle measurements from an E910.68 sun sensor that communicates through SPI by using Raspberry PI and Python library SPIdev.
Reading the datasheet I understood that I need to send a command (0x00) to read the values from the sensor and, to achieve this, the xfer2 command seems to do what I need, but I can't get how it works. Moreover, I read on the datasheet that, to activate the E910.68 enable measurements command, an SPI writes 011100XXYYP1ZDDD (where XX=function of X-diodes, YY=function of Y-diodes, P=enable/disable all photodiodes, S=operation mode (1=measurement enabled), Z=status of analog output (I don't need it), DDD=operation mode of analog output (don't need it)) has to be sent. I set it as 0b0111000000010000. This is what I did:

```
import spidev
import time

def main(args=None):
    spi = spidev.SpiDev()
    spi.open(0,0)

    spi.mode = 0
    spi.max_speed_hz = 5000000

    spi.xfer2([0b0111000000010000],2)

    while True:
        r=spi.xfer2([0x00],2)
        print(r)
        time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
     main()
```

What I get as a response is a constant value of [207].
What am I missing?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: E910.68 or E910.86? Surely you have a link to the product documentation to share if you are working with this? If you want folks to help you, it's generally a good idea to make it easy for them 

Comment: A couple of troubleshooting suggestions: (1) Lower SPI speed to 100kHz, (2) Shorten wire to 30cm, (3) Do a loopback test: (a) Put aside your Exxx.yy, (b) short/connect MOSI to MISO, (c) send something like 'abc' and see if you recv 'abc',